# How Do Get Tomcat Sessions ID by Java Class

Tags: java, class, session, tomcat, tomcat9

How do I retrieve Tomcat session IDs using a Java class?

I need to access the session IDs of active sessions in Tomcat programmatically. I've attempted to use various approaches, including implementing HttpSessionListener, but I haven't been successful. What is the correct way to obtain session IDs in a Java class within a Tomcat environment?

How can I terminate sessions programmatically using a Java class?

Once I have the session IDs, I want to be able to terminate specific sessions programmatically. I've tried using HttpSession.invalidate() method, but I'm unsure of the correct approach to identify and terminate a specific session. How can I reliably terminate sessions by their IDs within a Java class running in a Tomcat server?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
        Map<String, HttpSession> activeSessions = (Map<String, HttpSession>) context.getAttribute("activeSessions");
        if (activeSessions == null) {
            activeSessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            context.setAttribute("activeSessions", activeSessions);
        }
        activeSessions.put(session.getId(), session);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
        HttpSession session = se.getSession();
        ServletContext context = session.getServletContext();
        Map<String, HttpSession> activeSessions = (Map<String, HttpSession>) context.getAttribute("activeSessions");
        if (activeSessions != null) {
            activeSessions.remove(session.getId());
        }
    }
 }
```

To access the active sessions, you can retrieve the 'activeSessions' attribute from the 'ServletContext'.

example:

```
ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
Map<String, HttpSession> activeSessions = (Map<String, HttpSession>) context.getAttribute("activeSessions");
if (activeSessions != null) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, HttpSession> entry : activeSessions.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Session ID: " + entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

---

Assuming you have the session IDs and the map of active sessions, you can invalidate a session like this:

```
String sessionIdToTerminate = "someSessionId";
HttpSession sessionToTerminate = activeSessions.get(sessionIdToTerminate);
if (sessionToTerminate != null) {
    sessionToTerminate.invalidate();
    activeSessions.remove(sessionIdToTerminate); // Ensure to remove from the active sessions list
}
```

Remember to configure ur 'web.xml' to register the 'SessionListener'

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>example.package.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Didn't Understand this, please explain this and where i put this java file.

Comment: What don't you understand? The SessionListener class needs to be added to the listener in the configuration file. You need to use the Key in the Map based on a code that uniquely describes the user, and when you need to remove the session, get the corresponding session based on the user's unique code to make it invalid.